# Scraping google Document translation objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, google-translate

I trying to build an app which will translate documents, For that i am using google document translator this url (https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=docs&sl=en&tl=hi)
with this url i want to upload the document from user input.
Then i will **scrape** translated content from here (https://translate.googleusercontent.com/translate_f)
so in first step how do i upload document with document translate url?

This is what i have started with but unable link document to url.

```
NSString *urlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=docs&sl=%@&tl=%@", fromCode, toCode];
   
    [_webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlStr]]];
    [_webView reloadFromOrigin:self];
```

Any Thoughts or suggestions on this would be more helpful.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: @Lu_ i edited what i have started .